# ASP.NET Repeater Control - Referencing Individual Elements

Tags: asp.net, facebook, user-controls, asp.net-2.0, repeater

I have a repeater that displays a custom user control on a form multiple times as follows:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="MyRepeater" 
    ondatabinding="MyRepeater_DataBinding" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a name='<%# Eval("[\"Key\"]") %>' style="display: none;"></a>            

        <uc1:MyControl ID="Control1" runat="server" 
            Info='<%#Eval("[\"Info\"]") %>' Date='<%#Eval("[\"Date\"]") %>' 
             Key='<%#Eval("[\"Key\"]") %>' />/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Binding this to a SQL data source correctly displays the information that I expect:

```
    SqlDataSource.SelectCommand =
                "SELECT Info, Date, Key " +
                "FROM [dbo].[Test] ";
    SqlDataSource.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.Text;
    DataView resultsdv = (DataView)SqlDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

    MyRepeater.DataSource = resultsdv.Table.Rows;
    MyRepeater.DataBind();
```

What I can’t work out is how to reference an individual element of this to go directly to the specific item that I want, for example, to link an item from another web-site.  I’m  trying to use the Facebook “Like” function, and so I believe I need a URL that will take me directly to the item in question.  Can anyone point me in the right direction on this, please?

EDIT:

What I'm looking for is a way to reference a single item within the data repeater from outside the web-site.  For example:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/MyPage/InfoItem3
```

EDIT:

Changed above code to reflect answers given using an  tag.  Trying to reference the page using:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/MyPage#Key
```

e.g.

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/MyPage#10
```

Simply reloads the page

EDIT:

HTML from the user control:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
    var iframe = $("#likeButton");
    var newSrc = iframe.attr("src");
    newSrc += encodeURIComponent(location.href) + "<%= lblKey.Text %>";

    iframe.attr("src", newSrc);

});
</script>

<asp:Label runat="server" ForeColor="blue" Text="Date" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Smaller" ID="lblDate" Width="100%" />
<br />
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="Info" ID="lblInfo" Font-Size="Smaller" />
<br />
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="Key" ID="lblKey" Font-Size="Smaller" Visible="true" />
<br />
<iframe id="likeButton"
    src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=" 
    scrolling="no" 
    frameborder="0"         
    style="border:none; overflow:hidden; 
    width:450px; height:80px;">
</iframe>
<br />
```

Comment: 'http://www.mywebsite.com/MyPage/#Key' is not the correct format. As Tom pointed out, you should be using 'http://www.mywebsite.com/MyPage.aspx#Key'. The user control is a red herring - get your anchor tags working with just simple text in the repeater and then you can put the user control back in.

Comment: Thanks for this, and to Tom.  I'v edited the question as follows: www.site/page#key still only reloads the page.  I would have expected it to focus the browser on the specific element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code for your user control (you don't need Javascript):

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ForeColor="blue" Text="Date" Font-Bold="true" Font-    Size="Smaller" ID="lblDate" Width="100%" /> 
<br /> 
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="Info" ID="lblInfo" Font-Size="Smaller" /> 
<br /> 
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="Key" ID="lblKey" Font-Size="Smaller" Visible="true" /> 
<br /> 
<iframe id="likeButton" 
    src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<%# lblKey.Text %>"  
    scrolling="no"  
    frameborder="0"          
    style="border:none; overflow:hidden;  
    width:450px; height:80px;"> 
</iframe> 
<br />
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but the real problem that I have here is that http://mysite.com/page/#Key does not find the correct tag and seems to affect the master page formatting.

Comment: Hi, then you can try this:
    <a name='<%# Eval("[\"Key\"]") %>' style="visibility: hidden;"></a>
this is some bug that if you specify "display: none" then you can't use anchor.

Answer (score 2):

If you include an anchor tag, you would be able to reference it in the URL via the sharp mark:

http://www.site.com/page.aspx#Info

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="MyRepeater">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a name='<%# Eval("Info") %>' style="display: none;"></a>
        <uc1:MyControl ID="Control1" runat="server" 
                 Date='<%# Eval("Date") %>' 
                 Info='<%# Eval("Info") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: I added a display: none and removed the extra </a> tag from the (now deleted) other response.  See if that helps with the master page.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, and it caused the formatting of the master page to return to default formatting.

Comment: Can you please post an example of the ASP.NET or rendered HTML from within your UserControl?  And your masterpage would also be helpful.

Comment: See latest EDIT.  I'm not sure what you would want to see from the master page - it's basically a standard master page with a placeholder and some images (which don't display once the page is referenced as Page/#Key